# Using the Reflections library for querying resources in a given package ignoring subpackages

Tags: java, reflections

Using the [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), how to obtain all the resources with a particular file extension located exactly in one package ?

I tried with this code:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setUrls(...);
    cb.setScanners(new ResourcesScanner());
    FilterBuilder fb = new FilterBuilder();
    fb.include(FilterBuilder.prefix("org.p1")); //filtering resources in package "org.p1"
    cb.filterInputsBy(fb);
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(cb);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.xxx");
    Set<String> set = reflections.getResources(pattern); //resources having as extension "xxx" and located in package "org.p1"
```

But this is answering all the resources with extension "xxx" in the package "org.p1" **AND** in any subpackage inside it (e.g., "org.p1.p2").

Can I configure Reflections to answer only the resources located in "org.p1" and ignore its subpackages (if any) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try `Pattern.compile("org\\.p1\\.xxx");`?